# exemption from .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

[I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times, but none of the discussed solutions have worked for me.]

For a small website, I setup a directory structure on my localhost (`htdocs` folder) that essentially looks like the following (note that there is no `index.php` in root):

```
my-project/
    .htaccess
    config/
    public/
        # front-end files like index.php, login.php etc.
        assets/
            # css, data, img, js etc.
    src/
        # php logic, e.g. form evaluation, database queries/insertion, function definitions etc.
    templates/
    vendor/
```

I direct all requests to `public` using `.htaccess` (see below for its contents). While the redirect works, all form actions across front-end files like `<form action="../src/register.php" method="post"></form>` end up with a 404 error.

I suspect that the problem is that `src` is out of scope. How can I solve this, e.g. by making exceptions to the Rewrite Rule for all files in `src`?

Thank you.

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my-project/

# redirect everything to public/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
RewriteRule ^register.php$ src/register.php [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^register$ src/register.php [L]
```

So in form you have to use it like [www.example.com/register.php](http://www.example.com/register.php) it will be rewrite to [www.example.com/src/register.php](http://www.example.com/src/register.php). use absolute path in form action.

Comment: I inserted it right after `RewriteBase` due to the sequence of execution and it works, thanks. A short follow-up question: when the form validation is completed, I want to direct the user to some page. Why does the referral in say `src/register.php` using `header("Location: index.php")` not point towards `public/index.php` but to `src/index.php` as per my `.htaccess`? That is, why does my `RewriteRule` not take an effect?

Comment: you can write another rule like `RewriteRule ^index.php$ src/index.php [L]` or you can create generic rule using regex to rewrite all src files.